# Variants of Grönwall's theorem

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, ho.history-overview

Except the original Grönwall's theorem that $$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sigma(n)}{n \log \log n} = e^{\gamma},$$ and the two variants $$\limsup_{\begin{smallmatrix} n\to\infty\cr n\ \text{is square free}\end{smallmatrix}} \frac{\sigma(n)}{n \log \log n} = \frac{6e^{\gamma}}{\pi^2}$$ and $$\limsup_{\begin{smallmatrix} n\to\infty\cr n\ \text{is odd}\end{smallmatrix}} \frac{\sigma(n)}{n \log \log n} = \frac{e^{\gamma}}{2}$$ that have been proven [here](http://www.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/preprints/send?bid=2960), are there any other similar statements known?

Comment: Do you mean "similar statements" for the sum of divisors function $\sigma(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}d$? Because there are plenty of other multiplicative function for which similar asymptotics are known.

Comment: "that have been proven here," Where? 

Comment: I fixed the typos. Theorem 9 in the cited preprint contains 5 more similar asymptotics. I wonder what is wanted.

Comment: Maybe a statement with $\limsup_{\begin{smallmatrix}n\to \infty \cr n\in S\end{smallmatrix}}(\cdots)=d_S e^{\gamma}$. Where $d_S$ is the density of $S$.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear enough, it's my first question here, though. I mean similar statments for the $\sigma(n)$ function, not necessarily asymptotics, but anything that involves limit points of the function $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n \log \log n}$. For example, is there an important sequence $a_n$ such that $\frac{\sigma{a_n}}{n \log \log n}$ converges, besides the sequence of primes? A result that establishes the connection between the density and the limit superior? Etc. Nothing particular.

Comment: @nikmil: another important part of any question is **motivation** for it; this could encourage people to response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One example possessing a limit is the colossally abundant numbers of Alaoglu and Erdos,
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossally_abundant_number

where the limit of the Choie, Lichiardopol, Moree and Sole's 
 $$f_1(a_n) = \frac{\sigma(a_n)}{a_n \log \log a_n}$$
 is the same
$$ e^\gamma .$$
That is, the limit for these numbers is the lim sup for all numbers.

These are more natural than people realize. There is a simple recipe that takes some $ \epsilon > 0$ and gives an explicit factorization for the best value $n_\epsilon;$ see page 7 in the Briggs pdf
"Notes on the Riemann hypothesis and abundant numbers" at the bottom of the Wikipedia entry. The exponent of a prime $p$ in the factorization of $n_\epsilon$ is
$$    \left\lfloor \log_p \left( \frac{p^{1 + \epsilon} - 1}{p^\epsilon -1} \right) \right\rfloor   - 1                           $$

The process of making a sequence of "champion" numbers this way was invented by Ramanujan.